# synchronize () behaves badly here. Can any one fix this?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following class behaving so bad. It consists of 3 thread classes and the sequence is not correct and also the output. Anyone has any idea how to correct ?

**OUTPUT -**

```
ANOTHER MY_INT to 1
Got Change for MY_INT : 1
Incrementing MY_INT to 1
Incrementing MY_INT to 2
Got Change for MY_INT : 2
ANOTHER MY_INT to 2
Incrementing MY_INT to 3
ANOTHER MY_INT to 3
Got Change for MY_INT : 3
Incrementing MY_INT to 4
Got Change for MY_INT : 4
ANOTHER MY_INT to 4
Incrementing MY_INT to 5
ANOTHER MY_INT to 5
Got Change for MY_INT : 5
MY_INT:: 5
```

Code:

```
public class VolatilityTest {

private static int MY_INT = 0;

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    VolatilityTest vt = new VolatilityTest();
    vt.changeListener.start();
    vt.changeMaker.start();
    vt.anotherChangeMaker.start();

    /*new VolatilityTest().changeListener.start();
    new VolatilityTest().changeMaker.start();
    new VolatilityTest().anotherChangeMaker.start();*/
}

Thread changeListener = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                int local_value = MY_INT;
                while (local_value < 5) {
                    if (local_value != MY_INT) {
                        System.out.println("Got Change for MY_INT : "
                                + MY_INT);
                        local_value = MY_INT;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
});

Thread changeMaker = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                int local_value = MY_INT;
                while (MY_INT < 5) {
                    System.out.println("Incrementing MY_INT to "
                            + (local_value + 1));
                    MY_INT = ++local_value;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("MY_INT:: "+MY_INT);
    }
});

Thread anotherChangeMaker = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                int local_value = MY_INT;
                while (MY_INT < 5) {
                    System.out.println("ANOTHER MY_INT to "
                            + (local_value + 1));
                    MY_INT = ++local_value;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: It is refreshing to see "behaving so bad" instead of the more common "not working", but semantically it is not really better ...

Comment: what are you expecting? have you read any books/ articles on threading and sync locks? what are you locking on and how is it supposed to guard other variables which have different locks?

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want a specific execution order, why are you using threads at all?

Comment: You are not synchronizing at all since each thread uses its own lock. Use a global lock for all threads to synchronize. If its just an `int` you need to access concurrently, use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Take a look at the `compareAndSet` method.

Answer (score 9):

You are using each thread to synchronize its critical section. You must use a shared object, otherwise being in the critical section of a thread won't stop the other threads to entering theirs.

That is, in two different threads

```
// Thread 1
synchronize(this) {
    pointA
}

// Thread 2
synchronize(this) {
    pointB
}
```

Means that the program can be in `pointA` and `pointB` simultaneously.

Use a shared object to lock the critical sections from each other.

Additionally, think that synchronizing the critical sections will only prevent being executed at the same time, but it will not force them to execute in a given order.

UPDATE:

What you need to do to synchronize add

```
// add; any object can be used
private static Object sync_instance = new Object();

// and each synchronized section
synchronized(sync_instance) {...}
```

Comment: private static int MY_INT = 0; - would not that be a shared one as it is global ? So how do you want it to be implemented in your way ? Thanks.

Comment: What you need to share is the object that locks the `synchronized` section, too. Check update.

Answer (score 2):

as you are synchronizing on `this` each Thread will get independent lock ( `this` points to enclosing anonymous `Runnable()` instance). So there are 3 locks for 3 Threads, hence one thread can execute independent of another in any order.

What you need is a common lock to protect your shared variable MY_INT. Either you can use VolatilityTest.class as lock to guard MY_INT static variable.

```
Object lock = VolatilityTest.class;
```

Much preferably use a separate lock Object

```
Object lock = new Object();
.
.
.
synchronized(lock)
```

In order to synchronize order of execution

you Also need to use wait

```
synchronized(lock)
while(condition)lock.wait();
```

in each thread to await for a particular condition and notify when done

```
synchronized(lock)
lock.notifyAll()
```

This is traditional way of concurrent programming with implicit locking. However you might consider [newer High level java.util.concurrent constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package_description) before deciding. In particular see `CyclicBarrier` to control order of evaluation

Comment: +1 for mentioning the higher level constructs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a threadsafe counter.

If so, don't try to synchronize the threads that fiddle with the counter. Instead, use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) which in itself is threadsafe. So you can remove the `synchronized` statements from the threads.

```
private static AtomicInteger MY_INT = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

In the changelistener, use:

```
int local_value = MY_INT.get();
```

And the changemakers do

```
System.out.printline( "Incremented to " + MY_INT.incrementAndGet());
```